# PHP Code Cleanup (Multiple If, Else If, Else)

Tags: php

I have this chunk of code.  It works, but I'm sure there is a simpler and more logical way of doing it.  And just to save questions, `$seriespart` instead of `$row["SeriesPart"]` is specific because of previous code.

```
// normal titling convention is Number - Series - Series Part - Sermon
if ($row["Number"] && $row["Series"] && $row["SeriesPart"] && $row["Sermon"]) $title = $row["Number"]." - ".$row["Series"]." - Pt. ".$seriespart." - ".$row["Sermon"];
    // but sometimes a series doesn't have sermon titles
    else if ($row["Number"] && $row["Series"] && $row["SeriesPart"]) $title = $row["Number"]." - ".$row["Series"]." - Pt. ".$seriespart;
        // series that are in process don't have product numbers
        else if ($row["Series"] && $row["SeriesPart"] && $row["Sermon"]) $title = $row["Series"]." - Pt. ".$seriespart." - ".$row["Sermon"];
            // but sometimes a series doesn't have sermon titles
            else if ($row["Series"] && $row["SeriesPart"]) $title = $row["Series"]." - Pt. ".$seriespart;
                // and we don't want product singles just showing a sermon title (it should say S74 - Title as a distinction from other oddball sermons)
                // note the substr() as we want it to say S71 and not S0171
                else if ($row["Number"] >= "0100" && $row["Number"] <= "0199") $title = "S".substr($row["Number"], 2)." - ".$row["Sermon"];
                    // just show the bloody sermon title already
                    else $title = $row["Sermon"];
```

We have a bunch of sermons.  Those sermons are, usually, part of a series.  If a series is finished, it will have a series number, series title, series part, and optionally sermon title, sermon part, subtitle, and subtitle part.  If a series isn't finished, there won't be a series number.  Sometimes, there is no sermon title.  If it's not part of a series, then it can be an actual product unto itself.  Other times, it's just an oddball sermon that isn't a part of anything.

Examples...

> Made Healed (sermon only, not part of a series, oddball)
>
> S45 - Sucker Or Sower? (single that is a product)
>
> The Helper - Pt. 1 - Do You Need Help? (series in progress, no series number)
>
> 0513 - Harden Not Your Heart - Pt. 2 (completed series, no sermon title)
>
> 1101 - The Honor Of God - Pt. 11 - How God Honors Us - Pt. 5 - By Using Us - Pt. 3 (comleted series, sermon title - sermon part - subtitle - subtitle part)

Any ideas on how to clean up the code so I don't have to keep repeating the same information with if, else if, else?

Comment: How is the data stored? For something this (seemingly) complicated you might have better luck with XSL.

Comment: Why indent each condition as if it's _within_ the scope of the previous (and not as siblings, which they are)?

Comment: @ethrbunny The data is coming from MSSQL.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment Hmmm...I guess that's how I've always done it.  It just let me see that they were together (like doing } else { instead of putting them on individual lines).  Is that considered a bad practice?

Comment: @jeremyharris I will do click the up arrow for usefullness.  I didn't realize the check was to be clicked, as well.

Comment: @doubleJ: Re: Indentation - It doesn't hurt the performance of your application, but it is misleading. Your indentation suggests that each of the `else` statements are inside the previous statement's block. Putting the curly brace on the same line as the `else` is absolutely fine, and I don't think it's terrible to put the block of the if-statement on the same line as the condition, if the block is only one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
$parts = array();
if ($row["Number"] && ($row["Number"] < "Music01" || $row["Number"] > "Music99"))
{
    if ($row["Number"] >= "0100" && $row["Number"] <= "0199") $parts[] = "S". substr($row["Number"], 2);
    else $parts[] = $row["Number"];
}

if ($row["Series"]) $parts[] = $row["Series"];
if ($row["SeriesPart"]) $parts[] = "Pt. $seriespart";
if ($row["Sermon"]) $parts[] = $row["Sermon"];

$title = implode(" - ", $parts);
```

Comment: I think that did it.  I wouldn't have thought about creating an array for the parts.

Comment: `"Pt. $seriespart";` I figured that would need to be `"Pt. ".$seriespart;` but it works just fine.  Can variables be included in "" while functions can't?

Comment: @doubleJ: That's right. You can put a variable directly inside of a double-quoted string. I usually go a step further, and enclose the variable in curly braces, like this: `"Pt. {$seriespart}"`, and this helps for clarity on where the variable name ends. Functions cannot be done this way.

Comment: Included in that database are music albums that are set up in the same Number - Series (album title) - SeriesPart (track) - Sermon (song name) format.  I don't want to display the product number for music albums so I did `if ($row["Number"] >= "Music01" && $row["Number"] <= "Music99") $parts[] = NULL;`.  It wasn't specified earlier as I wasn't showing the product number the last time I tested the music albums.

Comment: @doubleJ: See updated answer (first if-condition). Instead of appending a `NULL` onto the array, just skip that part altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
$title = '';
if ($row["Series"] && $row["SeriesPart"]) {
    if ($row["Number"]) {
        $title .= $row["Number"]." - ";
    // series that are in process don't have product numbers
    }
    $title .= $row["Series"]." - Pt. ".$seriespart;
    if ($row["Sermon"]) {
        $title .= " - ".$row["Sermon"];
    }
// and we don't want product singles just showing a sermon title (it should say S74 - Title as a distinction from other oddball sermons)
// note the substr() as we want it to say S71 and not S0171
} elseif ($row["Number"] >= "0100" && $row["Number"] <= "0199") {
    $title = "S".substr($row["Number"], 2)." - ".$row["Sermon"];
}
// just show the bloody sermon title already
else {
    $title = $row["Sermon"];
}
```

And if you not want partialy creation

```
if ($row["Series"] && $row["SeriesPart"]) {
    if ($row["Number"]) {
        if ($row["Sermon"]) {
            $title = $row["Number"]." - ".$row["Series"]." - Pt. ".$seriespart." - ".$row["Sermon"];
            // but sometimes a series doesn't have sermon titles
        } else {
            $title = $row["Number"]." - ".$row["Series"]." - Pt. ".$seriespart;
        }
    // series that are in process don't have product numbers
    } else {
        if ($row["Sermon"]) {
            $title = $row["Series"]." - Pt. ".$seriespart." - ".$row["Sermon"];
        // but sometimes a series doesn't have sermon titles
        } else {
            $title = $row["Series"]." - Pt. ".$seriespart;
        }
    }
// and we don't want product singles just showing a sermon title (it should say S74 - Title as a distinction from other oddball sermons)
// note the substr() as we want it to say S71 and not S0171
} elseif ($row["Number"] >= "0100" && $row["Number"] <= "0199") {
    $title = "S".substr($row["Number"], 2)." - ".$row["Sermon"];
}
// just show the bloody sermon title already
else {
    $title = $row["Sermon"];
}
```